# Botón para cargar más elementos en NextJS

Tags: reactjs, api, nextjs

en nextJS estoy trayendo datos de una api y me gustaría implementar un botón para cargar 40 elementos más cada vez que se presione el botón y que cuando se haya alcanzado el máximo de elementos para mostrar, que el botón desaparezca.
El problema principal es que cuando hago click, me vuelve a recargar los mismos resultados que tengo en un principio.

el console.log(handleLoadMore) me arroja lo siguiente:

Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

26 |
27 | const handleLoadMore = () => {

> 28 |   setLimit((prevLimit) => prevLimit + 40);
> |  ^
> 29 |   if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
> 30 |     router.push(`/weapons?limit=${limit + 40}`);
> 31 |   }

Gracias de antemano.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const limit = context.query?.limit || 40;
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://eldenring.fanapis.com/api/weapons?limit=${limit}`
  );

  const { data: weapons } = await response.json();

  console.log(weapons);

  return {
    props: { weapons },
  };
};

const Weapons = ({ weapons }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [limit, setLimit] = useState(40);

  const handleLoadMore = () => {
    setLimit((prevLimit) => prevLimit + 40);
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      router.push(`/weapons?limit=${limit + 40}`);
    }
  };

  //console.log(handleLoadMore());

  return (
    <Layout
      title="Weapons"
      description="Weapons, Elden Ring Database, Enciclopaedia, game guide"
    >
      <main className="container">
        <h1 className="heading">Weapons</h1>

        <section>
          <h2 className="subtitle">Elden Ring Weapon Types</h2>

          <div className={styles.weapons_container}>
            {weapons.slice(0, limit).map((weapon) => (
              <WeaponCategories key={weapon.id} weapon={weapon} />
            ))}
          </div>
        </section>

        <button onClick={handleLoadMore}>Load more</button>
      </main>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Weapons;
```

Comment: Y que has probado para lograr esto? Por que en el codigo no se ve ningún error relacionado con lo que pides. Así no es como funcionamos aquí.

Comment: @ferter3006 Lo siento, estimado. De despistado habia pegado una versión anterior de mi código. Ahi lo corregí y reformulé mi pregunta. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Primero, cuando monta el componente deberias disparar la petición para que te cargue los primeros resultados segun el limit y offSet que establezcas; supongamos que estableces un estado local llamado Results;
segundo,
proba con algo así:

```
const loadMore = async () => {
    try {
      const next = await getMoreResults(pagination, currentPage * pagination);
      setResults((prevTransactions) => [...prevResults, ...next]);
      setCurrentPage((prevPage) => prevPage + 1);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error al cargar más resultados", error);
    }
  };
```

Y abajo renderizas los Results, entonces cuando carga más, te muestra más.